# Wireless (WPA2) keeps asking for password

Tags: wireless, network-manager, wpa2

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 (i686).

I read that there is one or more reported bugs related to this issue. I do not know if they are fixed as they appear to be in 11.10.

Here is HW info and what I have tried:

- The computer is Dell Latitude d510
- NIC is reported as a DWA-140 Ralink RT5372
- My desktop environment is XFCE
- The password is correct
- I tried available for all users
- I have wpasupplicant
- The connection works in Windows XP on the same machine
- Connecting to another wi-fi using WPA2/Enterprise seems to work

It worked but I needed a re-install. I have some succeeded connecting manually:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext && dhclient wlan0
```

This locates the problem to NetworkManager

Comment: Is the problem connection also WPA2/Enterprise?

Comment: @TheSchwa: No, it is not. DISCLAIMER: Perhaps need to check that network again in 14 days...

Comment: dropped a comment so i remember to VTC this as a bug when the bounty expires.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it's the same problem as I faced earlier.

I verified all the credentials and still I was getting the password prompt. Issue was with Authentication (encryption type). I changed that and it started working.

But as you said it's working in other OS, so it may be because of some bug. However I never faced this issue in 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about bugs. I had this problem on both Linux and Android and it ended up being faulty router firmware. After turning off all extended router features like "Protect 54G"  it started to work. You should  try first limiting router to the most basic protocol it supports, just to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

you got a lucky day

i hope someone will edit this answer & make it good "i am not good with desg :s"

if you are using to wireless connection with the same name or if you have been connected to a wireless network with the same name 
 lets check that
search for app name network 
wireless => if you find 2 with the same name choose the one that you do not need click on the "==>" button => then click on forget netowrk
elseif you have a 1 ssid with 
wireless => select the => click on "==>" button => if you see the strenth = good this is not a dc problem => settings => general => if the checkbox is checked this is not a ubuntu problem 
it is your hotspot/rooter problem 
here is a solution for that you can make the pc do what you"ve been doing

make a new name it whatever you want .

```
$ touch filename.conf
$ nano filename.conf
```

past this

```
network={
        ssid="your wifi name"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        proto=WPA
        pairwise=TKIP
        group=TKIP
        psk="your password"
}
```

do not forget to edit the ssid & the password "psk"
save the file then

```
$ pwd
$ ifconfig
```

after you finish that

go to startup applications => add => name whatever you like => 
command 
"try this first" 
 //wpa_supplicant -i "eth card name" -c "the output of $ pwd command & the filename " 
 the command will be just like this wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /home/username/Desktop/filename.conf => then click on add 
try to reboot if that did not workout you should trade the root password with the wireless password 
so if when you start your pc will ask you for only the root password this would be just like this 
$ sudo apt-get install gksu

then just like we did at the startup application this time it would be just like this 
gksu wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /home/username/Desktop/filename.conf

about your android you need to ask this in [dev xda forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/)

Comment: This is a good try to explain something you know, but you really need to print fullstops and Capitals where appropriate. What do you mean by search for app name? I have no button "==>" in the network manager xfce plugin.

Comment: @user877329 you can find that button in system settings => network
you will find that button in the line of the wireless name

Comment: Or better, post a screenshot.

Comment: here is some http://ge.tt/1kCm7jq1/v/0 take a look if you could not find it, i suggest to ask about network settings in xfce "i am not a xfce user"

Comment: Downwote since this is not XFCE but unity

Comment: 1st thing is I am here trying to help I am not looking for your rep 
2nd thing is if you got another question about this answer I am here
3d if you do not know how to access to system settings in xfce you better start asking this question because you can not ask 2 question in the same place & finally I suggest for to keep using xp because is good for people like you !